# Dealing with polymorphic association: is there such a thing as "too many" LEFT JOIN?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, entity-attribute-value

I have ten tables (Product_A, Product_B, Product_C, etc.), each of them having a primary key pointing to a row in a the parent table Product.

Basically, I have applied the recommendations coming from the SQL antipattern book from Bill Karwin (this antipattern solution described here: 
https://fr.slideshare.net/billkarwin/practical-object-oriented-models-in-sql/34-Polymorphic_Assocations_Exclusive_Arcs_Referential )

In order to load a child product, I use something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Product
LEFT JOIN Product_A USING (product_id)
LEFT JOIN Product_B USING (product_id)
LEFT JOIN Product_C USING (product_id)
LEFT JOIN Product_D USING (product_id)
WHERE product_id = 1337
etc.
```

I fear that the more types of child table products I get, the more JOIN clause I will have to add, causing the query to end up incredibly slow.

Is using LEFT JOIN in order to prevent polymorphic associations antipattern still a solution if we work on tens of sub child tables?

Should I start thinking of up using a query on parent table Product in order to grab a "product_type" and then execute another query on the appropriate child table depending on the value stored in the "product_type" column in the parent table?

Update: first replies on this topic state that this is bad design and that I should create a single table combining the colums from the child tables. But each product type has its own attributes. To say it otherwise: "A TV might have a pixel count, but that wouldn't make much sense for a blender." [@TomH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44955015/dealing-with-polymorphic-association-is-there-such-a-thing-as-too-many-left-j#comment76885703_44955015)

Thank you

Comment: Why do you have multiple product tables? Can't they be combined into a single table with a column to identify their type/grouping?

Comment: Is this a logic question for a class and you have to apply the solution using ten tables? This does not seem like good database design.

Comment: I would guess that each product type has different attributes. A TV might have a pixel count, but that wouldn't make much sense for a blender.

Comment: @TomH make a table called productattributes and relate it to products?

Comment: @JacobH Or Attributes - ProductsAttributes - Products

Comment: And now you either return multiple rows for a single product or you end up joining to the attributes table(s) multiple times - once for every attribute. On top of that, you have to determine which attributes (and how many) to join for at run time. You should read Bill Karwin's book, which I believe covers that model pattern.

Comment: @TomH thank you for your perfect understanding of the issue I am experiencing, any opinion on the the multiplication of "left joins"?

Comment: I think that Branko and Bill's approaches both have merit. In the end it's going to depend a lot on the specifics of your data and the application(s) that access the data. Test to see which approach works best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL has a hard limit on the number of joins. The limit is 61 joins, and it's not configurable (I looked at the source code and it's really just hard-coded). So if you have more than 62 product types, this is not going to work in a single query.

If the data were stored in the structure you describe, I would run a separate query per product type, so you don't make too many joins.

Or do a query against the `Product` table first, and then additional queries to the product-type specific tables if you need details.

For example, when would you need to gather the product-specific details all at once? On some kind of search page? Do you think you could design your code to show only the attributes from your primary `Product` table on the search page?

Then only if a user clicks on a specific product, you'd go to a different page to display detailed information. Or if not a different page, maybe it'd be a dynamic HTML thing where you expand a "+" button to fetch detailed info, and each time you do that, run an AJAX request for the details.

Comment: I was hoping to get an answer from you. You just made my day.

Comment: 61 - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/joins-limits.html .  (I had to check -- my [_Limits_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/limits) says 61.  Or is there a 63 elsewhere?

Comment: @RickJames, right, my mistake. It's 61 joins. Here's where I posted the research: https://www.quora.com/For-what-reason-is-the-maximum-number-of-tables-that-can-be-referenced-in-a-single-MySQL-join-61/answer/Bill-Karwin

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use the `product_type` (so called "discriminator") to help the DBMS produce a better query plan and avoid unnecessary joins. You can do something like this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Product
    LEFT JOIN Product_A
        ON product_type = 1 -- Or whatever is the actual value in your case.
        AND Product.product_id = Product_A.product_id
    LEFT JOIN Product_B
        ON product_type = 2
        AND Product.product_id = Product_B.product_id
    LEFT JOIN Product_C
        ON product_type = 3
        AND Product.product_id = Product_C.product_id
    LEFT JOIN Product_D
        ON product_type = 4
        AND Product.product_id = Product_D.product_id
WHERE
    Product.product_id = 1337
```

The DBMS should be able to short-circuit all "branches" that don't have the right `product_type` and avoid the corresponding joins.<sup>1</sup>

Whether this is actually better than using a separate query to fetch `product_type` and then choosing the corresponding "special" query (and incurring another database round-trip) - that's something you should test. As always, test on the representative amounts of data!

---

*<sup>1</sup> At least Oracle or SQL Server would do that - please check for MySQL!*

Answer (score 0):

What kind of data is going into these tables? Is it simply metadata about the products? If that's the case you could create a tall table that describes each product.

For example, a Product_Details table that has three columns: product_id, product_data_key, value. Where product_data_key is what used to be the columns in Product_A, Product_B, Product_C...

You could even have a separate table that better describes product_data_key so it's just a foreign key in Product_Details.

Comment: Each Product_A, Product_B, Product_C, etc. have columns defining attributes that really are specific to their own table, that would not make sense to append all those columns to the parent table Product, I would end up with a table having 20+ columns that are never related.

Comment: Gotcha. So yeah, a tall table may be what you need here. Take a look at [this article](https://powerpivotpro.com/2011/08/less-columns-more-rows-more-speed/). You basically end up converting all your columns from the extra tables into more rows in a single table.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe change your design? One product can have many attributes (and many of the same attributes), and those attributes have values.

I suggest three tables:

```
Products        ProductsAttributes      Attributes
-Product_Id     -Product_Id             -Attribute_Id
-...            -Attribute_Id           -Attribute_Name
                -Value                  -...
                -...
```

Using as such:

```
SELECT p.Product_Id, a.Attribute_Name, pa.Value FROM Products p
JOIN ProductsAttributes pa ON pa.Product_Id = p.ProductId
JOIN Attributes a ON a.Attribute_Id = pa.Attribute_Id
```

Then you can reuse attributes, tie them to products, and store their values. Each product only has the attributes that it needs.

Comment: This is known as Entity-Attribute-Value or "EAV", and is another can of worms altogether :)

Comment: EAV = Bad! Bad EAV, bad!

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic You guys and all of your proper terms :) I didn't know this had a name! What's the problem with using this?

Comment: In a nutshell, it makes it difficult to enforce constraints and produces excessive joins. If you google a bit (now that you know the proper term), I'm sure you'll find plenty of opinions on the topic!

Comment: [Read my book!](https://pragprog.com/book/bksqla/sql-antipatterns) ;-) Or see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8313090/mysql-table-structure-proposal/8313521#8313521 Or this blog: http://karwin.blogspot.com/2009/05/eav-fail.html Or this blog: https://www.simple-talk.com/opinion/opinion-pieces/bad-carma/

Comment: @BillKarwin Just got your book on Amazon. I've had to learn most of my SQL skills in the field, so this seems like a great read for me! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! My book does assume you know basic SQL syntax and usage. It's more about the best practices to solve common mistakes (which I have seen any times here on Stack Overflow).

Comment: @BillKarwin Yup, that is what I am looking for. I'm a DBA by trade but just past my first year doing that exclusively (previously web development). This book will be perfect like I said. I'm always trying to learn the proper ways to do things and just recently I'm challenging myself by answering questions on here. Thanks again. :D